# Update column with calculation and DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Transaction table and a Car table.

| tID | cID | carID | eID | tDate | PickupDate | ReturnDate | Amount_Due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | 1006 | 1004 | 104 | 2018-04-18 | 2018-04-28 | 2018-04-2 | NULL |

Car

| CarID | Make | Model | Type | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | Ford | Focus | Hatch | 2019 | 140.00 |

I need to update the Amount due column with `Price * DATEDIFF(day, [Transaction].PickupDate, [Transaction].ReturnDate)`

I know I need an inner join but not sure how to write the query correctly. This is what i have so far but I think it's way off. I'm very new to SQL

```
UPDATE [Transaction]
SET Amount_Due = INNER JOIN CAR ON [Transaction].carID=Car.carIS * (DATEDIFF(day, [Transaction].PickupDate, [Transaction].ReturnDate))
```

Comment: Have a look at this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#l-specifying-a-table-alias-as-the-target-object) in the documentation; you'll see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Nice one Stu, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in SQL Server for a `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` is:

```
UPDATE t
    SET Amount_Due = c.Price * DATEDIFF(day, t.PickupDate, t.ReturnDate)
        FROM [Transacction] t INNER JOIN
             CAR c
             ON t.carID = c.carID ;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon that worked, really appreciate the help. I'm not very familiar with aliases and what to clarify something. When you've put  't' after [Transaction] on line 3, same with car on line 4, is that creating the alias for the tables? Apologies if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @JosephRedding . . . Such questions when you are learning are not "stupid", just "basic".  In the above query, `t` and `c` are table aliases.  You can think of them as convenient abbreviations for the table references, although they are needed in come cases (such as when the `FROM` clause uses the same table multiple times).